# iOS Facebook sdk 3.5 openActiveSessionWithReadPermission Error Code 2

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login

I'm developing an iOS app that uses Facebook sdk 3.5. My app is compatible with iOS 5.0+.
I followed the How-to section of Facebook developer portal, for implement the login flow. In my app there are calls that required a publish permission and, agree with documentation, i get permission when i need, however i get only read permission in `appDelegate.m` as follow:

```
 - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
     NSArray *permissions =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email",nil];

    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermission:permissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
                 ^(FBSession *session,
                   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        }];  
}
```

As documentation explains, in the ViewDidLoad of First View Controller i check if FBSession token is valid. If not i recall the FallBack previously writed.

The problem of error code 2, presents when for first time i install the appplication in iOS 6.0+ and the facebook profile is setted yet: magically appears error and when i open the Settings-> Facebbok, the App is not granted. After this, i close the app, i set to 'On' the grant and application function. (i never set to off the permission of app in Settings->Facebook)

I read post of users with this problem and there are various type of solution, but anything solves my issue. In my case this is situation:

- I not ask any offline_access or publish_actions;
- Sandbox mode in Facebook Settings app is disabled;
- problem occurs also with permission array set to nil;
- i ask the publish actions only if needed in sharing functions;

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with you. 
Please check your Facebook app setting and disable Sandbox mode. **Because if enable, only app developers will be able to use app**

Hope this help for you